# The data set name is missing in the data region 'DataSetName'

Tags: sql-server-2005, reporting-services

I added an additional, new DataSet to my report and have been getting this cryptic error ever since.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue was that when the report had elements setup using the first data set I'd defined when the report was created.  Adding an additional data set reset the DataSetName value to be blank.  In this case for my Table but it could be for a List, etc.

To correct:

1. Open the report in SQL Server Business Intelligence Development Studio (AKA Visual Studio)
2. View the object details in the Properties Window (View > Properties Window or press F4)
3. Check the **DataSetName** value (under the Data section)
4. Update the value to point to the correct Data Set

Comment: I set the `DataSetName` in the **table's** properties in the layout tab. This corrected the issue

Answer (score 2):

Examine your RDLC file, open it in a XML editor.  Most specifically, take a look at the Dataset section.  See if there are some old ones that are still there.  You can edit this file directly, but be careful what you do.

You can also attempt to run the RDLC file through a XML validator, and see if it comes up with any errors.  Make sure to validate against the RDLC file's schema. (http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2005/01/reportdefinition/ReportDefinition.xsd)

Answer (score 2):

I had a bit of trouble finding the correct properties window that contained this value, so I will add the following:

1. On the Layout Tab, press F4 to bring the properties box up.
2. In the dropdown at the top of the properties box, find your table and select it.
3. You should now see that data section about halfway down, along with the DataSetName property the error is complaining about.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a decade late, but this is to possibly help the next guy that is searching the internet for answers (like me).

In SSRS, right-click any unused/white area of the report then choose Select-> and the Group level (not group level content) that you are getting the error about.

In the properties window (Menu->View->Check Properties) for the Group Level, scroll down to General the DataSetName. Select the drop down arrow and choose the original dataset.